# Skipping authorization for certain methods

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authorization, filter

Per the Agile Development book, I have an `Admin` MVC that controls how users log in. In `ApplicationController`, I have a `before_filter` that checks for authorization. So, this will check that the user has logged in for *every* page.

The problem is that I want *everyone* to be able to access the `new` method, for example, in Users (that is, anyone should be able to create a new user -- naturally! Only admin users should have access to the other methods in UsersController such as `edit`, etc.). What's the best way to do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can either of this

```
before_filter :except=>[:method_name]  #methods you want to skip filter
```

OR

```
before_filter :only=>[:method_name]    #methods you want to be filtered before called.
```

EDITED

```
before_filter :filter_method, :except=>[:method_name]  #methods you want to skip filter
```

OR

```
before_filter :filter_method, :only=>[:method_name]    #methods you want to be filtered before called.
```

Comment: If this filter is specified in `ApplicationController` then it will only be applied to those methods in all child controllers as well.

Comment: @john before_filter :authorize, :except=>[:new, :create]  in UsersController will also work.

Comment: @John Nice..I haven't realized that haha.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [`skip_before_filter`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Filters/ClassMethods.html#M000533) method in child controller classes to skip the default filter processing. For example:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  skip_before_filter :authorize, :only => [:new, :create]
end
```

—Will skip the before filter named `:authorize` only for the `new` and `create` actions within the users controller i.e. the filter will still get applied for all other actions.

Answer (score 0):

I would also suggest using CanCan gem for authorization as it has a really simple and clean way to define authorization rules.
http://github.com/ryanb/cancan